# How to set cambria math as math font for pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

How can I make pdflatex use cambria for math fonts and uarial for the body font?

Comment: There is no Type1 version of Cambria Math, as far as I know.

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX?

Comment: You can use Arial (or, more likely, an Arial clone) for text but there is nothing you can do to use Cambria if pdfLaTeX is a must. (Unless there is a type1 version or you have permission to create one *and* you are prepared to write the required support package.)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, I  know that it works with LuaLaTeX, the question was just out of curiosity if this is also available for pdflatex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Cambria Math is only available as an OpenType font and necessarily depends on its OpenType Math table, it does not work with pdftex and needs luatex or xetex.