# how to represent these symbols from Word in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, publishing, paper

[image: \scriptP]
\scriptP in Word,

[image: \scriptp]
\scriptp in Word.

What are the representations in LaTeX?

Comment: tried \mathcal{P}, but seems not the same and it only has upper-case symbols.

Comment: `\mathcal` is the same but you are probably using a different font, word is most likely using cambria math which isn't easily available in pdflatex but can be used from xelatex or lualatex

Comment: for lowercase see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373513/a-calligraphic-font-with-small-lowercase-letters

Answer (score 4):

The default math font in Word in Cambria. If you use Cambria, then these symbols are available. I show how to use Cambria with ConTeXt and perhaps someone could add how to use it in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

```
\setupbodyfont[cambria]
\starttext
${\cal Pp}$
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418921/5001) for an equivalent solution that's based on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX analogue to [Aditya's conTeXt-based answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418860/5001). Observe the use of the `Cambria Math` math font and the `\mathscr` ("script math") macro.

Incidentally, the third character shown below, sometimes (frequently??) called "Weierstrass-p", is available in basic LaTeX -- no need to employ the `Cambria Math` Opentype font...

[image]

```
%%% compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria} % optional
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P}$ $\mathscr{p}$ $\wp$
\end{document}
```

Comment: the last "p" is used for weierstrass elliptic functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_p ),  it shouldn't be used for anything else.  (unicode originally had it assigned to the "power set", but that's uppercase, as well as having not at all the same meaning; unicode is fixed now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for this thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what you want to achieve.

If it's lower case calligraphic letters you are after try.

```
\usepackage{dutchcal}

\begin{document}
  pP $pP \; \mathcal{pP}$
\end{document}
```

[image: dutchcal]

If you go down this road checkout this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231348/106458)

If you want to typeset all math in 'Cambria Math' you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286936/how-to-set-cambria-math-as-math-font-for-pdflatex))

A simple implementation could be

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
  pP $pP \; \mathscr{pP}$
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\mathscr` instead of `\mathcal` as the latter does only provide upper case calligraphic variants.

I do not have 'Cambria Math' installed on my system so I can only provide a screenshot with 'Stix 2'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P}\quad \wp$
\end{document}
```