# Change font for a specific command

Tags: fonts, macros, mathcal

I would like to change the font associated specifically with `\mathcal` to `cambria` rather than the default font without changing the rest of the document.

How may I do that? I don't mind setting up a `newcommand` which calls both the font and `mathcal` in order to do so but I don't want the text around it to change font from whatever mathmatical font is set by default.

Thanks

Edit:
As requested I simply want to produce what is discussed in this thread:
[how to represent these symbols from Word in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418856/how-to-represent-these-symbols-from-word-in-latex) Without changing the font of the entire document, i.e. the `cambria` font should only be in effect for the `\mathcal` command.

My thought is there must be a way which incorporates `\newcommand` in order to set a new command which is able to act like `\mathcal` but also changes the font to `cambria`.

Edit 2:
For those of you who may be using `pdflatex` you will need to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and add the following lines in your preamble so that the mathfonts are pretty much the same as in `pdflatex` with `cambria` `\mathcal`:

```
%In Texmaker change the options for quickbuild to XeLaTeX + View PDF or LuaLaTeX + View PDF 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[range=\mathcal]
\renewcommand{\boldsymbol}[1]{\symbfit{#1}} %You can continue to use \boldsymbol.
\let\mathbb\relax
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
%Document info
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, do please tell us whether you use pdfLTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX (or something else entirely) and whether your document loads the `fontspec` and/or `unicode-math` packages.

Comment: I am not certain, I am using a very simple and default version of Texmaker to produce my TeX files, I am able to load any of the packages that you've suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that Cambria is available for `pdflatex`. Here's a simple setup for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}% or whatever
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[range=\mathcal]

\begin{document}

$a+b\in\mathcal{C}$

$
\mathcal{A}
\mathcal{B}
\mathcal{C}
\mathcal{D}
\mathcal{E}
\mathcal{F}
\mathcal{G}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I am facing a couple of issues when I try to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, for some reason `\mathbb` appears differently than in `pdflatex` and as well the `\boldsymbol` command which I sometimes use in math equations doesn't work as it would in `pdflatex`. Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: I was able to configure `\mathbb` through the following: `\let\mathbb\relax`
`\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}` but `\boldsymbol` seemingly doesn't work in the math environment.

Comment: Disregard my previous statements `\renewcommand{\boldsymbol}[1]{\symbfit{#1}}` was able to fix boldsymbol.